# How to get the all content below the "colspan" selector?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am sending a POST request to filter the IDs then parse the output. I need to get all the content below the colspan selector (The DESIRED OUTPUT is shown in the end). Under `colspan="4"` there are lots of `b`,`table` tags and it contains `tbody` > `tr` > `td` but my script returns only `b` tags' content.

The URL: https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases
[image]

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

request_headers = {
    'authority': 'e-mehkeme.gov.az',
    'method': 'POST',
    'path': '/Public/Cases',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,'
              'application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en,en-GB;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'content-length': '66',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'origin': 'https://e-mehkeme.gov.az',
    'referer': 'https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',
}

voens = {'1303450301',
         '1700393071',
         '2002283071',
         }


form_data = {
    'CourtId': '',
    'CaseNo': '',
    'DocFin': '',
    'DocSeries': '',
    'DocNumber': '',
    'VOEN': voens,
    'button': 'Search',
}

url = 'https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases?courtid='

response = requests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=request_headers)
s = bs(response.content, 'lxml')

# PRINT THE HEADERS!
sHeader = s.findAll('tr', {'class': 'centeredheader'})[0]
headers = [sHeader.get_text().strip()]
print(headers)

# PRINT THE CONTENTS OF EACH SEARCH!
for voen in voens:
    form_data['VOEN'] = voen
    idData = [string for string in s.select("td", colspan_="4")]
    print(idData)
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Ətraflı məlumat: 

İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib 
Abiddin Hüseynov - sədrlik edən hakim
Azad İmanov - tərkib üzvü
Vahid Sadıqov - tərkib üzvü

Tərəflər 
Cavabdeh: ƏLİYEV HAFİZ RAMİZ
İddiaçı: "OPTİMAL ELEKTRONİKA" MƏHDUD MƏSULİYYƏTLİ CƏMİYYƏTİ

İşin mahiyyəti
Müqavilələrdən əmələ gələn öhdəliklər üzrə mübahisələr
```

Comment: I don't see all that content in the response.

Comment: did you run it? what is wrong with the string?

Comment: I searched the response for the terms you want as output and couldn't find all of them.

Comment: Did you mean to do a loop of requests rather than just one to get the different voens?

Comment: I want to loop of voens ( post request for each voen ) and get the searched outputs' content as i mentioned in question, i solved the loop i think but the content is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a POST with each updated voen value in a loop and extract the ids and make new requests.

```
import requests,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = {'VOEN': '', 'button': 'Search'}

voens = ['1303450301', '1700393071', '2002283071']

for voen in voens:
    data['VOEN'] = voen
    r = requests.post('https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases', data=data)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
    ids = [i['value'] for i in soup.select('.casedetail')]
    for i in ids:
        r = requests.get(f'https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/CaseDetail?caseId={i}')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        print([re.sub('\n|\r|\n','',i.text.strip()) for i in soup.select('[colspan="4"]')])
```

Comment: `re.sub` which variable is re?

Comment: It's an imported library. See imports at top.

Comment: ERROR:`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/valizadavali/PycharmProjects/webScrap/taxbyID.py", line 54, in <module> response = s.post(url, data=form_data, headers=request_headers) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`\

Comment: Please try running with rollback above

Comment: It doesn't like Session cookies so reverted to new requests.

Comment: works great! but when I am searching in the website manually it returns lots of results but with the script, it return only one

Comment: `https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases` there is a button like a thing that swings named `AXTARIŞ`

Comment: thanks for your effort but the thing I want is when you click each result it pops out a small window with detailed information about the each result, i will share the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201509/discussion-between-vali-valizada-and-qharr).